# Where can I find a mountain bike in Grand Theft Auto V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've done the first two missions in GTAV and then spent a couple of hours messing around exploring San Andreas.

I'd really like to get my hands on a mountain bike so I can ride around Mount Chiliad.

So far the bike rental shop at the bottom of the Mount Chiliad gondola has only spawned road bikes.

Does anyone know where I can find a mountain bike? The closer to Mount Chiliad the better.

Answer (score 2):

I went back to the Mount Chiliad gondola and a mountain bike had spawned.

Since I hadn't done any more missions (so hadn't progressed any further in the game) this suggests the spawn is either random or time dependent (certain times of the day?)

[image: Mountain bike at bottom of Mount Chiliad gondola]

Comment: I think you can also buy them online, if you don't want to go around looking for one.

Comment: "find" is in the question title.

Answer (score 2):

The beaches in the North-West have a few bikes. Their owners are nearby with a campfire/tables and chairs etc.

I've only found front-suspension bikes so far, but there appear to be a few variations - i.e. mudguard, no-mudguard.

Answer (score 1):

One place is down on Vescuppi Beach; it's featured when Michael races Jimmy from the bike rental stand to the pier.